# Java - Testing Simulation With Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm not very well-versed with Mockito but am trying to use mocks to test behaviour of a simulation, this is the class:

```
package simulator;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate;
import simulator.enums.Team;
import simulator.fixtures.Fixture;

public class SimulateBasketballMatchResult implements Simulation<Team> {

    private final Fixture fixture;

    public SimulateBasketballMatchResult(Fixture fixture) {

        Validate.notNull(fixture, "fixture cannot be null");

        this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    @Override
    public Team simulate(Map<Team, Double> outcomeProbabilityMap) {

        Validate.notNull(outcomeProbabilityMap, "outcomeProbabilityMap cannot be null");

        final Team homeTeam = fixture.getHomeTeam();
        final Team awayTeam = fixture.getAwayTeam();

        double random = randomDoubleGenerator();

        double homeWinProbability = outcomeProbabilityMap.get(homeTeam);

        return random < homeWinProbability ? homeTeam : awayTeam;

    }

    public Double randomDoubleGenerator() {
        return Math.random();
    }

}
```

Below is the test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SimulateBasketballMatchResultTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

    private static final Map<Team, Double> MATCH_RESULT_PROBABILITY_MAP = new HashMap<>();

    private static final Fixture FIXTURE = new Fixture(GOLDEN_STATE_WARRIORS, HOUSTON_ROCKETS, REGULAR_SEASON);

    static {
        MATCH_RESULT_PROBABILITY_MAP.put(FIXTURE.getHomeTeam(), 0.7d);
        MATCH_RESULT_PROBABILITY_MAP.put(FIXTURE.getAwayTeam(), 0.3d);
    }

    @Mock
    private SimulateBasketballMatchResult simulateBasketballMatchResult;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnGoldenStateWarriorsAsWinner() {

        when(simulateBasketballMatchResult.randomDoubleGenerator()).thenReturn(0.5d);

        assertThat(simulateBasketballMatchResult.simulate(MATCH_RESULT_PROBABILITY_MAP), is(GOLDEN_STATE_WARRIORS));

    }

}
```

I would like to assert that `GOLDEN_STATE_WARRIORS` is returned when the probability range is between 0 and 0.7- however I get an assertion error of null with my test code.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <GOLDEN_STATE_WARRIORS>
     but: was null
Expected :is <GOLDEN_STATE_WARRIORS>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Mock
private Fixture fixture;

private SimulateBasketballMatchResult simulator;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    simulator = spy(new SimulateBasketballMatchResult(fixture));
    doCallRealMethod().when(simulator).simulate();
}

@Test
public void shouldReturnGoldenStateWarriorsAsWinner() {
    doReturn(0.5).when(simulator).randomDoubleGenerator();
    when(fixture.getHomeTeam()).thenReturn(GOLDEN_STATE_WARRIORS);
    when(fixture.getAwayTeam()).thenReturn(HOUSTON_ROCKETS);

    assertThat(simulator.simulate(MATCH_RESULT_PROBABILITY_MAP), is(GOLDEN_STATE_WARRIORS));
}
```

`Mockito.spy` and `@Spy` allow you to mock some methods of a **real** object, but `Mockito.mock` and `@Mock` mock the whole object.

> A **mock** in mockito is a normal mock (allows you to stub invocations; that is, return specific values out of method calls).
>
> A **spy** in mockito is a partial mock (part of the object will be mocked and part will use real method invocations).
>
> [Read more](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13)

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much. What does `spy` actually do and how is it different to mocking?

Answer (score 2):

`simulateBasketballMatchResult` is a mock object, so by default, it will return `null` for all its methods (that have a non-primitive return value, of course).

Instead of **mocking** that object, you should probably **spy** it:

```
@Spy
private SimulateBasketballMatchResult simulateBasketballMatchResult = 
    new SimulateBasketballMatchResult(Fixture);
```